# Generate List<> of custom object

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following requirement

I have a Employee class:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int ID{get; set;}
    public string EmpFName{get; set;}
    public string EmpLName { get; set; }
}
```

I want to do something like this when creating values

```
var Emp = new List<Employee>[]{

                new Employee{id=1, EmpFname="matt", EmpLName="Cook"},
                new Employee{id=2, EmpFname="mary", EmpLname="John"}

            });
```

How can i do this?

Comment: Removed linq tag as the question has nothing to do with LINQ. Please always tag your questions appropriately.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're already nearly there. This code should work:

```
var emp = new List<Employee>
{
    new Employee{ID=1, EmpFname="matt", EmpLName="Cook"},
    new Employee{ID=2, EmpFname="mary", EmpLname="John"}
};
```

The features involved here are implicit typing, object initializers and collection initializers. All of them are covered in C# in Depth chapter 8, which is available for free download from the [Manning C# in Depth site](http://manning.com/skeet).

Comment: Dam you Jon Skeet why are you so fast lol :).  I was just about to submit the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Umm. I don't think it's linq related but you can do this:

```
var emps = new List<Employee>() {
  new Employee() { ID = 1, EmpFname="matt", EmpLName="Cook" }
};
```